# Graphic override subcategories Family

Tags: revit

I would like to ask if anyone know the trick to do surface pattern graphic override for subcategories on the view template?

Such as a window, i would like to glass to be blue but the frame to be black, is this possible? I have searched the internet but it seem that there are currently no solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a product expert or application engineer, so I do not know the optimal user interface workflow. However, afaik, programmatically in the Revit API, you generally assign different ***materials*** to each separate component of the window, e.g. glass for the glass and wood for the frame. Maybe this automatically leads to different subcategories as well. In any case, the different materials are obviously rendered differently and enable the colour control you require.